# 'BeginContext' does not exist in the current context error on app start up

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error on start up of an app, centering on Line 55 which says:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'BeginContext' does not exist in the current context.

Can someone tell me how to begin troubleshooting this. I have not been able to pull up any useful information anywhere.

```
Line 53: #line default
Line 54: #line hidden
Line 55: BeginContext(__razor_helper_writer, "~/App_Code/Content.cshtml", 120, 11, true);
Line 56: 
Line 57: WriteLiteralTo(__razor_helper_writer, "    <script");
```

Below is the event from the Event Viewer corresponding to the above error.

```
Event code: 3007 
Event message: A compilation error has occurred. 
Event time: 4/15/2015 3:14:20 PM 
Event time (UTC): 4/15/2015 7:14:20 PM 
Event ID: 3f4801a217314f3394ed5e6674b219dc 
Event sequence: 3 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: 32d13f5d-1-130735988590606624 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\AppDirectory\AppDirectory\AppDirectory\AppName\ 
    Machine name: LocalMachine 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 7832 
    Process name: WebDev.WebServer40.exe 
    Account name: DOmain\UserName 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpCompileException 
    Exception message: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\3eb1bc6a\ccb7ac89\App_Code.djdhx8mc.0.cs(55): error CS0103: The name 'BeginContext' does not exist in the current context
   at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   at System.Web.Compilation.CodeDirectoryCompiler.GetCodeDirectoryAssembly(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories, Boolean isDirectoryAllowed)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectory(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectories()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://localhost:45627/ 
    Request path: / 
    User host address: 127.0.0.1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: DOmain\UserName 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 4 
    Thread account name: DOmain\UserName  
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   at System.Web.Compilation.CodeDirectoryCompiler.GetCodeDirectoryAssembly(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories, Boolean isDirectoryAllowed)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectory(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectories()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)

Custom event details:
```

EDIT (Based on Comment From Bart):

```
@using System.Web.Mvc;
@using Program.ExtensionMethods;
@helper Script(string scriptName, UrlHelper url)
    {
    <script src="@url.Content("~/Scripts/" + scriptName)" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
@helper SourceScript(string scriptName, UrlHelper url)
    {
    <script src="@url.Content("~/SourceScripts/PageScripts/" + scriptName)" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
@helper CSSScript(string scriptName, UrlHelper url)
    {
    <link href="@url.Content("~/Content/" + scriptName.FindCSSFile())" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
@helper SourceScriptNoCache(string scriptName, UrlHelper url)
    {
    <script src="@url.Content("~/SourceScripts/" + scriptName.FindFile("SourceScripts"))" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
@helper ImageURL(string applicationPath, string imgPath)
    {
        string appPath = applicationPath != "/" ? applicationPath + "/" : "/";
    @String.Format("{0}Content/Images/{1}", appPath, imgPath);
}
@helper IFrameURL(string applicationPath, string iFramePath)
    {
        string appPath = applicationPath != "/" ? applicationPath + "/" : "/";
    @String.Format("{0}{1}", appPath, iFramePath);
}
@helper Trunc(string source, int strLen = 50)
{
    string result = null;

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(source) && source.Length > strLen)
    {
        result = source.Substring(0, strLen - 3) + "...";
    }
    else
    {
        result = source;
    }

    @result;
}
```

Comment: see "~/App_Code/Content.cshtml", line 120

Comment: There is no line 120 in that file it only goes to line 43

Comment: maybe it's char 120 line 11. Does that file have Global Razor Functions on it? can you post the Content.cshtml file ? also which version of mvc 4 or 5?

Comment: @Bart ... I posted the cshtml file it was referring to above in an edit.

Comment: one thing : @Url should be uppercased U, and it's lowercase in your pasted code. I don't think this is really the problem tho. this error happens when razor compile your views. Removing the Content.cshtml should make the error goes away. Remove it and start adding methods to see if there's an offending one or any thing inside will give you an error, in that case, there's more a compilation problem with your MVC dll and version mismatch (configuration on web.config inside your views folder) and your web.config on root. Which mvc version? inspecting web.config files (both) may give you a hint.

Comment: Thanks Bart ... your suggestion  about the Web.config / dll mismatch turned out to be the solution... See my answer below for details. (I have to wait till tomorrow to accept it as the answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it ... I am not 100% sure why this worked, but ....

Going on what Bart suggested about a web config / dll mismatch, I renamed the `System.Web.Mvc.dll` and rebuilt the app and it started working again...

Answer (score 0):

From A quick Google search I found that changing the config file to below can fix the problem.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```