# CSS style {Display:none} is not working in htmlattribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am using CSS style `display: none` in the `TextBoxFor` call,  but it's not working.

```html
<img id="Img" src="~/abc/def.jpg" style="height: 120px; max-width: 100%; width: 280px;" class="img-responsive" />
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.dP,  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control has-feedback-left file btntag", @onchange = "openFile(event)", @style="display: none;", @type="file", placeholder = "Upload Display Picture" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dP, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id="Img" src="~/abc/def.jpg" style="height: 120px; max-width: 100%; width: 280px;" class="img-responsive" />
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.dP,  new { @class = "form-control has-feedback-left file btntag", onchange = "openFile(event)", style="display: none;", @type="file", placeholder = "Upload Display Picture" } )
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dP, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

The above is the correct way to define html attributes for helpers. (Remove the extra "htmlAttributes = new" part.)

Comment: I codeed it as you suggested me but now i am facing new compilation error ......BeginContext("~/Views/UserRegistration/UserRegistration.cshtml", 12489, 14, true);

Answer (score 0):

Change your TextBoxFor syntax to below.

`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.dP,  new { @class = "form-control has-feedback-left file btntag", onchange = "openFile(event)", style="display: none;", @type="file", placeholder = "Upload Display Picture" })`

only `class` and `type` requires a prefix of `@` as those two are C# keywords. So to resolve the ambiguity prefix it with `@` to make it a HTML attribute as `@class` and `@type`

Also remove the `htmlAttributes` part. The basic syntax is as below.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { ... })  // ... is your HTML attributes
```

Comment: I codeed it as you suggested me but now i am facing new compilation error ......BeginContext("~/Views/UserRegistration/UserRegistratio‌​n.cshtml", 12489, 14, true);

Comment: @TittiTowel can you show the full error. If you can add a image and give me link that is fine too.. to give image link you can use http://imgur.com/

Comment: @TittiTowel looks like its caused by something else.. look into this thread http://stackoverflow.com/q/29659267/2592042